# netplan bridge ethernet and wifi so that device on wifi can be accessed though ethernet interface

Tags: networking, wireless, ethernet, netplan

I'm trying to bridge the ethernet and wifi interfaces of a raspberry pi 4 running ubuntu 20, and using netplan.

The idea is to be able to access a device that has a wifi hotspot, through the ethernet interface.

My current netplan is -

```
network:
  version: 2
  renderer: NetworkManager
  ethernets:
    eth0:
      dhcp4: false
      addresses: [10.10.10.223/24]
      gateway4: 10.10.10.1
      nameservers:
       addresses: [8.8.8.8,8.8.4.4]
      optional: true
  wifis:
    wlan0:
      dhcp4: true
      optional: true
      access-points:
        "DEVICE":
          password: "DEVICE123"
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Please see `https://netplan.io` and `https://netplan.io/examples`.

Comment: If you are using NetworkManager, then NetworkManager is the more appropriate place to set this up. Netplan YAML would be more appropriate if you were using networkd.